# JFileChooser showing wrong current directory

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have the following code. The problem is when I select some directory in FileChooser (ex. `C:\Windows\System32`) it prints: `C:\Windows` (always one level lower than it actually is).

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
chooser.setDialogTitle("Wybierz folder z logami");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
  path = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
  jLabel1.setText(path);
```

Comment: You want `chooser.getSelectedFile()` not `chooser.getCurrentDirectory()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentDirectory()` returns the path of the directory currently displayed. If you choose a child directory inside the *current* directory, it is considered the currently *selected file*.

Thus use `getSelectedFile()`, even though you know it is in fact a directory.